# query with two tables with condition OR

Tags: php, mysql

So I have two tables and I want do query to select which `login` and `pwd` same in the two table to get the result so I do that query in below but return result the one table and the other when I changer the login contains in the other table  any result so I do OR in MYsql :

```
select tab1.*,tab2.* from tab1,tab2 where 
tab1.login='name@yahoo.com' and tab1.pwd='123' 
or tab2.email='nme@yahoo.com' and tab2.pwd='123';
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: A plain password in DB is a big risk. Use a password hashing mechanism to encrypt it and then save it to DB.

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). Even [if you are escaping inputs, it's not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187) You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API instead of concatenating user-provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Comment: You need to use brackets, but I think it's better to do two querys, one per table. Otherwise, we get into table fields and join considerations. It's simplier a query per table. Another alternative, if both tables have same fields, is to make a view mixing both tables, so you can just query on that view.

Comment: The question is not clear to me. Please follow [ask]

Answer (score 1):

you can use brackets to ensure correct order of operations

```
select tab1.*,tab2.* from tab1,tab2 
where ( tab1.login='name@yahoo.com' and tab1.pwd='123' ) or (tab2.email='nme@yahoo.com' and tab2.pwd='123') ;
```